What is the best choice to take webRTC track objects and stream it to a streaming CDN to distribute it to Watchers?
Iam developing a live Video streaming web application as a personal project, i already developed a client that stream video and audio to a streaming server through a signaling server using webRTC, the peer connection between the client and the streaming server is established successfully and track objects reaches to the streaming server successfully.
peerConnectionMap[id].addEventListener('track', async (event) => {
        console.log('track', event.streams)
    });

I see the tracks reach successfully when the peer connection is established.
Iam completely clueless about what should i do next, I can imagine using a tool called ffmpeg to convert track objects to HLS form and stream it to a CDN.
I searched alot in cloud services that can provide a streaming cdn for free because i can't use paid services, thus i couldn't find any free choices.
what should I consider? i saw many names like (Node media server , Nginx as a CDN , HAProxy as a load balancer). is thier any thing i should consider or i should read about to get the complete picture?
iam using node js: react js for the client, socket.io to establish peer connection, and express as the server
